# Isn't it a bit early for the April fool's joke?

Tags: discussion, april-fools

Just noticed the April fools item is showing up.

Current time here is L  Thursday, March 31, 2016 @ 7:52 PM

[image]

Answer (score 20):

[Unlike last year](http://jericson.github.io/2015/03/31/yolks_on_us.html), the joke is still fun:

> It's not even April 1 in my timezone and I'm already sick of April Fools' Day.

As with [Winter Bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245123/1438) we try to be generous with timezones on April 1:

> Unless the requirement mentions a specific timezone, hats that are date-based are often awarded for 14 hours before and 12 hours after the specified date in UTC, to accommodate people everywhere in the world. This means you can earn such a hat even though for you it's not even that day yet.

The upshot: more fun for more people. And who can't get behind that?